# std::unique_ptr char array

Tags: c++, c++14

I found a strange behavior when using std::unique_ptr with arrays, please see:

```
 {
   auto v = std::make_unique<unsigned char []>(10);
   assert(v);
   std::cout << std::hex << v.get() << std::endl; // does not print anything
 }
 {
   auto v = std::make_unique<char []>(10);
   assert(v);
   std::cout << v.get() << std::endl; // does not print anything
 }
 {
   auto v = std::make_unique<uint8_t []>(10);
   assert(v);
   std::cout << v.get() << std::endl; // does not print anything
 }
 {
   auto v = std::make_unique<std::array<uint8_t, 10>>();
   assert(v);
   std::cout << v.get() << std::endl; // works, prints address
 }
 {
   auto v = std::make_unique<uint16_t []>(10);
   assert(v);
   std::cout << v.get() << std::endl; // works, prints address
 }
```

What's the reason why it doesn't work for byte size arrays? Am I missing something trivial? The above behavior is consistent for C++14 Clang 3.8, gcc 4.9 and 5.2. I read the C++ standard and didn't find something relevant, it would be nice to have an answer that addresses this behavior.

Comment: ostreams have special handling for pointers of characters, since that's what makes `std::cout << "hello world\n"` work. The equivalent line for the array versions would be `std::cout << v->data()`.

Comment: if you cast the result of get() to void* it works, too

Comment: I found a *lot* of potential duplicates ... someone should probably sort through them and pick a canonical question.

Comment: It works with (void*), thanks!

Comment: It's because `operator<<` treats those type as legacy C strings so will attempt to print them as such. If you want their address, you can cast them to a type that will be *treated* as an address: `std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<void*>(v.get()) << std::endl;`.